# How to enable transaction timestamp in MySQL binary log to include microseconds part of the time

Tags: mysql, aws-dms, mysqlbinlog

I needed some help from the community on an issue I am stuck with. We use AWS DMS to read from the MySQL binary logs to captures changes.

Our Production system is active, meaning multiple transactions can happen over a second. But it seems MySQL captures transaction timestamp in binary log only up to second precision. Is there a way or an approach like changing binary log variables or some setting to enable Binary logs to capture the microseconds part of the transaction too?

I have done a lot of reading and no solution talks about ways to enable this feature. Mostly it stops to the statement that the Timestamps in the binary log uses TIMESTAMP data type which is 32 bit and hence can not store microsecond precision of the time.

But there should be a way to make this work.

Regards,
Pankaj Tiwari

Comment: That sounds like a pretty low-level thing in the binary log format specification itself. It's unlikely to be easily adjusted.

Comment: Thanks, tadman. I saw that MySQL has Binary Logging has Options and Variables available that can be changed, couldn't find one that allows the timestamp to include microsecond precision.

Comment: You could always add a column with such precision to your table. Why do you need it in the binary log?